# Get certain row from mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm a starter with mysql and I have a little problem.

I've got an list in php ( all data from an mysql database ) : example

- item1
- item2
- item3
- item4
- item5

Now all these items are links.

What I want is if I click at 1 of those links, a div shows up and contains the id of the item.

There are 2 columns in my database ( id & name ).

So item1 etc. is the name and id is what has to show up.

How can I do this?

Comment: I havent tried any codes, just did some research but haven't found a tutorial or a simular question on another forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually your question is about a bit ajax or jquery. anyhow,

```
echo '<ul>';
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo ("<li id='clickme'>$row['name']<span id='yourvariable'>$row['id']<span></li>");
}
echo '</ul>';
```

then you need trigger Jquery to show them.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#yourvariable').fadeIn('fast').delay(800).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

I tried to give the you main idea. Code may contain syntax faults. Hope this works for you.